# What happens when Sickening Radiance meets Darkness or Fog Cloud?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Sickening Radiance is described as:

> Dim, greenish light spreads within a 30-foot radius sphere centered on a point you choose within range. The light spreads around corners, and it lasts until the spell ends.
>
> When a creature moves into the spell's area for the first time on a turn or starts its turn there, that creature must succeed on a Constitution saving throw or take 4d10 radiant damage, and it suffers one level of exhaustion and emits a dim, greenish light in a 5-foot radius. This light makes it impossible for a creature to benefit from being invisible. The light and any levels of exhaustion caused by this spell go away when the spell ends.

Is the radiant damage of Sickening Radiance reduced or eliminated by Darkness or Fog Cloud?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Sickening Radiance vs. Darkness

The **Darkness** spell has this qualification:

> If any of this spell's area overlaps with an area of light created by
>   a spell of 2nd level or lower, the spell that created the light is
>   dispelled.

**Sickening Radiance** is a 4th level spell and is not affected by **Darkness**. You would be able to see the dim, greenish light in the darkness and affected normally by the radiant damage of **Sickening Radiance**.

### Sickening Radiance vs. Fog Cloud

Neither of these spells' descriptions have any interactions listed. Both should be able to co-exist without interference. You would be able to see the dim, greenish light in the fog and be affected normally by the radiant damage of **Sickening Radiance**.

Comment: Yep. And Darkness specifies that nonmagical light can't illuminate it - but obviously light from a spell like Sickening Radiance would be magical light, and would penetrate the portion of the Darkness where the areas of effect of the two spells overlap.